# How do I add a newline in a markdown table?

Tags: markdown

I have the following cells in a markdown table:

| something | something that's rather long and goes on for a very long time | something else |
| --- | --- | --- |

I'd like to be able to insert a break in the middle line, so the middle column isn't so wide. How can I do that in Markdown? Do I need to use HTML tables instead?

Comment: When using `<br>` be careful that you don't leave any space in the front(indentation). I've had the same problem but when I removed the tab space it worked.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

Use an HTML line break (`<br>`) to force a line break within a table cell:

```
| something | something that's rather long and <br>goes on for a very long time | something else |
|-----------|---------------------------------------------------------------|----------------|
```

Rendered:

| something | something that's rather long and goes on for a very long time | something else |
| --- | --- | --- |

Comment: The <BR> syntax works only when you convert to HTML - at least in `pandoc`.

Comment: The `<br>` syntax also works on GitLab, which uses [Redcarpet Ruby library](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for Markdown processing ([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html))

Comment: To whomever edited this answer on 14 November 2020: You have introduced a syntax error by adding a backslash to the tag.  Backslashes don't close tags in HTML. I can't edit the answer myself because of the minimum character limit.

Comment: This works for Obsidian as well

Comment: @ Psychonaut I have just edited the answer to remove the syntax error in the `<br>` tag (someone has added a space + trailing slash which is wrong)

Comment: The `<br>` syntax also works on Azure Databricks markdown cells

Answer (score 67):

When you're exporting to HTML, using `<br>` works. However, if you're using pandoc to export to LaTeX/PDF as well, you should use [grid tables](http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-grid_tables):

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | first line\   | first line\        |
|               | next line     | next line          |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Bananas       | first line\   | first line\        |
|               | next line     | next line          |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Sublime Text has a nice package for this: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Table%20Editor It is no longer maintained, but everything is still fine with it!

Comment: Why didn't they invent this from the very beginning into markdown?!

Comment: I'm using Markdown Preview Extended in VSCode to generate PDF with LaTeX via Pandoc. I put `\newline` (a LaTeX command) inside the table, which passes through because there is an option to allow raw tex. However, this text appears in the preview browser.

Answer (score 17):

Use `<br/>` . For example:

```
Change log, upgrade version

Dependency | Old version | New version |
---------- | ----------- | -----------
Spring Boot | `1.3.5.RELEASE` | `1.4.3.RELEASE`
Gradle | `2.13` | `3.2.1`
Gradle plugin <br/>`com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties` | `1.4.16` | `1.4.17`
`org.webjars:requirejs` | `2.2.0` | `2.3.2`
`org.webjars.npm:stompjs` | `2.3.3` | `2.3.3`
`org.webjars.bower:sockjs-client` | `1.1.0` | `1.1.1`
```

URL: https://github.com/donhuvy/lsb/wiki

Comment: This seems to be a copy of the other answer from four years earlier.

Comment: <br/> works with readme.io.  I tried \\ as explained above and that did not work withr reame.io.

Comment: Yes, <br/> works for Readme. e.g: Microsoft VSCode previewing Markdown document.

Answer (score 17):

Just for those that are trying to do this on `Jira`. Just add `\\` at the end of each line and a new line will be created:

```
|Something|Something else \\ that's rather long|Something else|
```

Will render this:

[image]

Source: [Text breaks on Jira](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=breaks)

Comment: Nice answer. Also here's a hug for having to use JIRA: 

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work in other markdown viewers I use (e.g. Bitbucket.org or Markdown viewer Chrome browser extension by Simov)

Answer (score 4):

The newline `&#10;` or carriage return `&#13;` ASCII codes might work if your renderer doesn't handle HTML and `<br/>`, but supports characters like non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`).

For instance:
`|Something | Line 1 &#10; line 2 | Something else|` works fine in my case, but not in the stackoverflow interpreter...

Comment: Interesting - if you add the markdown implementation or app this applies for to your answer I'll upvote the answer

Comment: Thanks! The only way to get it to work in Mattermost

Comment: `&#10;` works great in Obsidian.md in addition to `<br>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to use `pandoc` to do this, the [documentation of Pandoc says the following](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#paragraphs):

> A backslash followed by a newline is also a hard line break. Note: in multiline and grid table cells, this is the only way to create a hard line break, since trailing spaces in the cells are ignored.

When e.g. attempting to convert Markdown to HTML or RTF, using the following syntax actually renders linebreaks in table cells both for RTF and HTML output:

```
Hello | World | Test
------+-------+-------
This | is \\\n a long \\\n text with \\\n linebreak | Toodeloo
```

Here, the characters `\\` mean "a single backslash" and `\n` mean a newline character; you will need to make sure you encode it correctly depending on how/if/where you generate the markdown.

I just spent quite a while to make this work and thought I'd share my insights here.

For those interested, my use case is to generate markdown (as it's easier), convert it to RTF or HTML using `pandoc`, then copy this into the clipboard for pasting into Microsoft Teams. I know, this could be totally automated using webhooks, but this is enough for this use case. Side note: On macOS, using `pandoc -t rtf -s <input.md> | pbcopy` works, on Windows, you need to use `pandoc -t html -s <input.md> | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml` in Powershell to make this work.