# Breaking https links in markdown table without breaking the hyperlink

Tags: markdown

I am creating tables in markdown and I have web links that are long so on adding the links to the column it expands the current column and shrinks the other columns thus making the table look uneven and hideous.
[Here is the screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1rqY.png)

I tried two of the StackOverflow answers where one of them suggests `<br />` which breaks the link but then the part that goes to the next line is no longer the part of the web link. For example, consider the link **https://somewebsit.com/page1/page2/pasge3/pag4/**
When I did this in markdown

```
https://somewebsit.com/page1/<br />
page2/pasge3/pag4/
```

the part "page2/pasge3/pag4/" no longer belongs to the hyperlink

I also tried using `\\` syntax to break the lines but that also behaves the same way as `<br />`.

Is there any way to maintain the continuity of hyperlink on the next line as well.

Posts referred:
[Newline in markdown table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700487/newline-in-markdown-table) 
[How to add new line in Markdown presentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33191744/how-to-add-new-line-in-markdown-presentation)